# How to proper healthcheck a db2 container so my app container can go up safely?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, db2

Currently i am just waiting a somewhat safe time frame before up the app container inside this docker-compose file:

```
# this compose spins up a db2 database for development purposes
version: "3"
services:
  db2: # https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2
    #    image: ibmcom/db2:11.5.8.0
    image: icr.io/db2_community/db2:11.5.8.0
    privileged: true
    expose:
      - 50000
    ports:
      - "50000:50000"
    environment:
      LICENSE: accept
      DBNAME: sample
      DB2INSTANCE: db2inst1
      DB2INST1_PASSWORD: change-me-please
    healthcheck:
      # TODO find a real health check for db2
      test: [ "CMD", "sleep", "300"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 301s
      retries: 3
  app:
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: ./src/infrastructure/Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 7070
    ports:
      - "7071:7070"
    environment:
      APP_PROFILE: compose
    depends_on:
      db2:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: on-failure
```

Is there any db2-specific tool able to give me better healthchecks?
Any guidance is welcome.
For context, the entire project is [here](https://github.com/sombriks/sample-kotlin-db2).

Comment: There is a [db2gcf](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-db2gcf-control-db2-instance) utility which must be run on the server locally either as root or db2 instance owner (db2inst1 in your case). That is: `db2gcf -s`. It returns the corresponding return code to check if needed.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, it rather depends on how the instance will get used, which might vary per person. In some cases "health" might mean fitness for intended purpose , or suitability of the default configuration settings for the intended purpose, or absence of Severity:Severe messages in the diagnostics, or ensuring that the database is active etc etc. "Health" of an instance or database might be a relative term...

Comment: @MarkBarinstein thank you so much, that tool does almost exactly what i need, still face a few restarts on app container but startup times are way better now. please promote your comment to a full answer so i can mart it as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [db2gcf](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-db2gcf-control-db2-instance) utility which must be run on the server locally either as root or db2 instance owner (db2inst1 in your case). That is:
`db2gcf -s`
It returns the corresponding return code to check if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this healthcheck is to connect to the database using this test (replace the property between <> by the value) :

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "su - db2inst1 -c \"db2 connect to <DB_NAME> user <USER_NAME> using <PASSWORD>\""]
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
```

Docker will attempt to connect to the database at regular intervals to ensure that it is available. If the command fails, Docker will consider the container to be "unhealthy".